# Couldn't Upload Directory: MSBuild and Jenkins Issue

Tags: c#, msbuild, ftp, jenkins

I've spent a whole day battling with an issue I haven't been able to resolve.  The issue is that I am in the process of moving a Jenkins CI environment to another server and along with that creating another job in Jenkins to deal with live deployment.  The live deployment takes place on a new server rather than the development server.  I am having a problem right at the end of the process.

The output for deployment to UAT is:

```
GenerateSampleDeployScript:
  Sample script for deploying this package is generated at the following location:
  C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\UAT\Mcfc\Build\WebServices\FulfillmentWebService\obj\UAT\Package\FulfillmentWebService.deploy.cmd
  For this sample script, you can change the deploy parameters by changing the following file: 
  C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\UAT\Mcfc\Build\WebServices\FulfillmentWebService\obj\UAT\Package\FulfillmentWebService.SetParameters.xml
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\UAT\Mcfc\Build\WebServices\FulfillmentWebService\FulfillmentWebService.csproj" (Package target(s)).
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\UAT\Mcfc\scripts\main.xml" (Transfer target(s)).

Build succeeded.
```

But the deployment to live returns this:

```
GenerateSampleDeployScript:
  Sample script for deploying this package is generated at the following location:
  C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\Production\Mcfc\Build\WebServices\FulfillmentWebService\obj\Production\Package\FulfillmentWebService.deploy.cmd
  For this sample script, you can change the deploy parameters by changing the following file: 
  C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\Production\Mcfc\Build\WebServices\FulfillmentWebService\obj\Production\Package\FulfillmentWebService.SetParameters.xml
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\Production\Mcfc\Build\WebServices\FulfillmentWebService\FulfillmentWebService.csproj" (Package target(s)).
C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\Production\Mcfc\scripts\Production.xml(143,5): error : CDUP successful. "/Mcfc/Production/SOA/AuctionWebService" is current directory.
C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\Production\Mcfc\scripts\Production.xml(143,5): error : 
C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\Production\Mcfc\scripts\Production.xml(143,5): error : Couldn't upload directory.
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\Mcfc\Service\Production\Mcfc\scripts\Production.xml" (Transfer target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

The relavant portions of the deployment script are as follows:

```
142 <Target Name="Transfer" DependsOnTargets="Package">
143    <FtpUploadDirectoryContent
144    ServerHost="secret"
145    Port="21"
146    Username="secret"
147  Password="secret"
148    LocalDirectory="$(LocalBuild)\WebServices\AuctionWebService\obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp"
149    RemoteDirectory="Mcfc/$(Configuration)/SOA/AuctionWebService"
150    Recursive="true"
151     />
```

I've had an issue with this the whole day, so all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending the last slash character to the LocalDirectory attribute value as follows:

```
LocalDirectory="$(LocalBuild)\WebServices\AuctionWebService\obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\"
```

You can also try to recompile the FtpUploadDirectoryContent task so that it includes the stack trace when it logs exceptions to get a more detailed error message.